# closure function issue javascript

Tags: javascript

my random number works correctly, but my counter does not. my counter should add one each time the button is clicked, instead it just shows 1 why does it not? Im not getting any console errors. Im not sure what the problem is. I am suppose to be using closure functions. which I believe im doing correctly.

**html**

```
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="showNumber()">Number</button>
    <p id="counter"></p>
    <p id="ran_num"></p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function showNumber() {
    var number1 = 0;
    var counter1 = 0;

    var randomNum = (function() {
        return function() {
        return number1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);}
    })();

    var counterNum = (function() {
        return function() {
        return counter1 += 1}
    })();

    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Count = " + counterNum();
    document.getElementById("ran_num").innerHTML = "Random Number = " + randomNum();
}
```

Comment: What is the point of an IIFE that literally just returns a function with nothing special to it?

Comment: In any case, every time you call `showNumber`, you are resetting `number1` and `counter1`, re-creating new `randomNum` and `counterNum` functions and these will run completely independently of any previous calls.

Comment: when does `counterNum` is called ? `my counter should add one each time the button is clicked` => where is the `click` event handler ?

Comment: @pomeh - in HTML. :)

Comment: @nevermind doh ! I was looking for an `addEventListener` call, damn me :-( thanks though

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol if i knew what an IIFE meant before i googled it, I might be able to answer that, but I dont, I stated that I was trying to use a closure function, and that I believed I was doing it correctly. Cleary I am confused. but thanks for that super helpful comment,

Comment: The way you have your code set up with the iife you'd have to counterNum()(); invoke the function then invoke the returned function.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `counter1` to maintain its state between calls of `showNumber`, then it should NOT be defined inside it. Instead, try something like this:

```
(function() { // this is your closure
    var counter = 0;
    function randomNum() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 1;
    }
    function counterNum() {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }

    function showNumber() {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "Count = " + counterNum();
        document.getElementById('ran_num').innerHTML = "Random Number = " + randomNum();
    }

    // make showNumber accessible in the global scope:
    window.showNumber = showNumber;
})();
```

Comment: is this whats consider a closure function? Im confused as to what a closure function is. Is it just a function called within a function, that can access the variables of the function its wrapped in?

Comment: To understand closures read this article, should be informative and easier to understand to someone new on the subject http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Answer (score 0):

Using most of your existing code

```
function showNumber() {

    var randomNum = function() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }

    var counterNum = (function() {
        var counter = 0;
        return function() {
            return ++counter;
        }
    })();

    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Count = " + counterNum();
    document.getElementById("ran_num").innerHTML = "Random Number = " + randomNum();
}
```